# ESP8266 flush program after power lost

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I program my ESP8266 with a Arduino Uno and this guidance: [Programming the ESP8266 With the Arduino IDE in 3 Simple Steps](https://dzone.com/articles/programming-the-esp8266-with-the-arduino-ide-in-3)

Wifi connect, Mqtt connect (subscribe, publish, callback) everything works fine and totally like expected.

But after I disconnect the power from the Arduino Board and reconnect to a another V3.3 power source, the ESP8266 behavior is like a complete clean flushed device and nothing happens.

For programming I use this settings (Arduino IDE 1.8.12):

[image]

What I am doing wrong here?

### EDIT

1.) I try two different ESP8266, and 3 different scretches (1. proved working in the past, 2. simple blink sketch, 3. sketch with my code I need)

2.) the program stops immediately after disconnecting **CH_PD** from 3.3V

3.) I update the esp8266 board package to the newest version *2.6.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is my bad documentation. After a long time, I found the solution *again* here: [Easiest ESP8266 Tutorial (Using arduino)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao5XcORsYxA). Like the first time two years ago. In conclusion, I forgot to disconnect **GPIO0** from **GND** after programming.

The correct way after programming is:

- disconnect arduino
- disconnect gpio0 from gnd
- connect power to esp8266

Thanks to LiveSparks creating and uploading this great video.